# How to avoid "No Tables Found" while web-scraping a list of urls in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I know this has to do with looping the URLs, but I thought my for loop was correct.

The code that some amazing person helped me with to scrape specific tables from ONE site is here:

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://magicseaweed.com/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/"
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# table 1
regex = re.compile("^table table-primary.*")
table1 = soup.find("table", {"class": regex})
df1 = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(table1)))[
    0].iloc[:9, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 15]]
res1 = [df1.columns.values.tolist(), *df1.values.tolist()]
# print(res1)

# table 2
tables = soup.findAll("table")
table2 = tables[0]
df2 = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(table2)))[0]
res2 = df2.values.tolist()
# print(res2)

# table 3
table3 = tables[1]
df3 = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(table3)))[0]
res3 = df3.values.tolist()
print(res3)
```

It's amazing. I wanted to build off it though and scrape these three tables from MULTIPLE URLS.  I added in a for loop, with the ID list, but I can't understand why I'm getting a "No Tables Found" result.  I'm trying to better learn this stuff - can someone explain why this is happening/what I'm doing wrong? I feel I'm so close, but stuck.

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


id_list = [
    '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683',
    '/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/',
    '/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/',
    '/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/',
    '/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/',
    '/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/',
    '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
    '/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/',
      
]


for x in id_list:

    url = 'https://magicseaweed.com' + x
    html = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # table 1
    regex = re.compile("^table table-primary.*")
    table1 = soup.find("table", {"class": regex})
    df1 = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(table1)))[
        0].iloc[:9, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 15]]
    res1 = [df1.columns.values.tolist(), *df1.values.tolist()]
    print(res1)

    # table 2
    tables = soup.findAll("table")
    table2 = tables[0]
    df2 = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(table2)))[0]
    res2 = df2.values.tolist()
    print(res2)

    # table 3
    table3 = tables[1]
    df3 = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(table3)))[0]
    res3 = df3.values.tolist()
    print(res3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your urls, they should be valid in syntax to get the right response back - First one of your examples goes to an 404.

Also try to keep your script simpler, there is no need for separat use of `BeauftifulSoup` it is still and well handled by `pandas` under the hood.

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

id_list = [
    '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
    '/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/',
    '/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/',
    '/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/',
    '/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/',
    '/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/',
    '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
    '/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/',
      
]

for x in id_list:
    print(pd.read_html(requests.get('http://magicseaweed.com' + x).text)[2].iloc[:9, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 15]])
    print(pd.read_html(requests.get('http://magicseaweed.com' + x).text)[0])
    print(pd.read_html(requests.get('http://magicseaweed.com' + x).text)[1])
```